# Can we link Teams with Yammer such that any post on Teams is linked on Yammer

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

We want to automate any new conversations in a team on Teams to Yammer with a link and title of the post.

Is it possible to achieve this? Any recommendations appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But I hope my answer helps.

You can use Power Automate, with the following bare minimum setup:

1. Trigger: [Microsoft Teams > When a new Channel message is added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#when-a-new-channel-message-is-added), you need to select which Teams and which Channel. And make sure your account is part of the Teams as well.
2. Action: [Yammer > Post mesage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/yammer/#post-message). You need to select which Yammer group to post.

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly as we wanted it to

Comment: Glad that help!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using [Microsoft Viva Engage](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-viva/engage) which is [essentially what Yammer is evolving in to](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2023/02/13/yammer-is-evolving-to-microsoft-viva-engage-with-new-experiences-rolling-out-today/). Engage is available in Microsoft Teams.